# Filemaker Pro 12 create a summary table

Tags: database, relational-database, one-to-many, filemaker

Good day,

Can someone please help me with this. I am working on a short quiz game. I am having trouble viewing a summary of all the attempts.

I have two tables. Table 1 records a player’s quiz attempts (Players proceed’s to the next level if score is equal or above 50). For each attempt it makes a new record. For example let's say this is my table in filemaker Pro 12

```
Table Name(PLAYER_ATTEMPTS_TB)
Attempts_ID >>Player_ID >> Player_Name >> Game_Level    >> Score
1         Player001 >> John Smith  >> Level 1   >> 30
2         Player001 >> John Smith  >> Level 1   >> 40
3         Player001 >> John Smith  >> Level 1   >> 45
4         Player001 >> John Smith  >> Level 1   >> 55
5         Player001 >> John Smith  >> Level 2   >> 26
6         Player001 >> John Smith  >> Level 2   >> 40
7         Player001 >> John Smith  >> Level 2   >> 45
8         Player001 >> John Smith  >> Level 2   >> 60
9         Player001 >> John Smith  >> Level 3   >> 30
10        Player001 >> John Smith  >> Level 3   >> 40
11        Player001 >> John Smith  >> Level 3   >> 48
12        Player001 >> John Smith  >> Level 3   >> 70
etc…
```

Attempts_ID is the Primary Key

So what I’m tryin to do is create a summary table that shows all the attempts that are equal or above 50 for each player.

So on the table below I show the summary for all of the levels.

```
Table Name(PLAYER_SUMMARY_TB)
Summary_ID >>Player_ID >> Player_Name >> Level1_Score >> Level2_Score >> Level3_Score
1        Player001 >> John Smith  >> 55  >> 60 >> 70
2        Player002 >> Simon Cowell>> 55  >> 60 >> 70
etc…
```

Summary_ID is the Primary Key

The two tables have a relationship, Linked by the Player_ID field. In the “PLAYER_SUMMARY_TB” Table, I have made the score fields Calculation type and I have entered the following:

```
If( PLAYER_ATTEMPTS_TB::Game_Level = Level 1 ; Max(PLAYER_ATTEMPTS_TB:: Score))
```

This shows me the correct results with the above if statement but as soon as I change the condition to “Level 2”, I do not get any results back. I am not sure what I’m doing wrong? The two tables are linked using the Player_ID. Player_ID is the Primary key on the PLAYER_SUMMARY_TB and a foreign key on the PLAYER_ATTEMPTS_TB.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your "summary table" is basically a Players table and it would be best to treat it as such - for example by including the player's names in it (once) instead of repeating them in the Attempts table.

There are several ways you can summarize the Attempts table. First and foremost, you can produce a summary report of the table itself, summarized by PlayerID and by Level. To exclude scores below a certain threshold, perform a find as a first step of producing the report.

Another option is to use filtered portals on the Players layout, one portal per Level (or, if you prefer, use a single portal and a global field to select the level being shown).

Yet another way is to add a Levels table, and show the results in a portal to that table (though this is a little difficult to describe properly in a few short sentences). It's also not quite clear if you want to show **all** attempts above the threshold,or only the top score - this method would only show the latter.

---

The reason why your calculation cannot work is because the expression:

```
PLAYER_ATTEMPTS_TB::Game_Level
```

is evaluated using data from the **first** related record.

Comment: FileMaker 12+ also gives the SQL option, so a query like "SELECT MAX(Score) FROM PLAYER_ATTEMPTS_TB WHERE `Player_ID` = ? AND `Game_Level` = ? AND Score >= 50" should work as a calculation for the LevelN_Score fields.

Comment: Hi, @michael.hor257k and pft221. Thanks for your quick response. Let me try out the options. I'll let you know how it goes.